# has netstat been replaced with a new tool?

Tags: command-line, netstat

**Has netstat been replaced by a newer program?**

I noticed netstat is part of the nettools package which was replaced by ip command.

**What program should i be using to check see open/listening ports on my local computer?**

Comment: I you lazy like me you can still install old good netstat: sudo apt install net-tools

Answer (score 43, accepted):

the netstat command has been deprecated in favor of the faster, more human-readable ss command. See recommendations from [RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-networking-monitoring_and_diagnosing_performance_problems), [Debian](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/net-tools/netstat.8.en.html), and [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration) regarding the deprecation of net-tools, including netstat, with iproute alternatives, specifically ss.

The ss command is a tool used to dump socket statistics and displays information in similar fashion (although simpler and faster) to netstat.

```
$ ss
```

is replacing netstat.
You can use it like this:

```
$ ss -aunp | grep radi
```

Comment: This answer can be improved by linking to any public statements suggesting a coordinated effort to replace `netstat` with `ss`.

Comment: The `netstat` or 'ss' 's answer are more one page. I using Ubuntu server. (no GUI) How can shows paged? (same is -p switch in `dir` command of windows cmd)

Comment: Use standard shell piping to the "more" pager.

`ss -anut | more`

Answer (score 24):

I use "show sockets":

```
sudo ss -ltpn
```

This command also shows the associated processes:

```
State         Recv-Q         Send-Q                    Local Address:Port                   Peer Address:Port
LISTEN        0              128                             0.0.0.0:111                         0.0.0.0:*             users:(("rpcbind",pid=844,fd=8))
LISTEN        0              100                             0.0.0.0:8080                        0.0.0.0:*             users:(("java",pid=1554,fd=60))
LISTEN        0              128                       127.0.0.53%lo:53                          0.0.0.0:*             users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=1048,fd=13))
LISTEN        0              128                             0.0.0.0:22                          0.0.0.0:*             users:(("sshd",pid=1891,fd=3))
LISTEN        0              1                             127.0.0.1:8005                        0.0.0.0:*             users:(("java",pid=1554,fd=76))
```

Swap `-t` with `-u` for UDP instead of TCP.

In the beginning I always used `-ltpan`, but sometimes that shows a bit much.

`ss -h` (help on Ubuntu 18.04):

```
Usage: ss [ OPTIONS ]
       ss [ OPTIONS ] [ FILTER ]
   -h, --help          this message
   -V, --version       output version information
   -n, --numeric       don't resolve service names
   -r, --resolve       resolve host names
   -a, --all           display all sockets
   -l, --listening     display listening sockets
   -o, --options       show timer information
   -e, --extended      show detailed socket information
   -m, --memory        show socket memory usage
   -p, --processes     show process using socket
   -i, --info          show internal TCP information
   -s, --summary       show socket usage summary
   -b, --bpf           show bpf filter socket information
   -E, --events        continually display sockets as they are destroyed
   -Z, --context       display process SELinux security contexts
   -z, --contexts      display process and socket SELinux security contexts
   -N, --net           switch to the specified network namespace name

   -4, --ipv4          display only IP version 4 sockets
   -6, --ipv6          display only IP version 6 sockets
   -0, --packet        display PACKET sockets
   -t, --tcp           display only TCP sockets
   -S, --sctp          display only SCTP sockets
   -u, --udp           display only UDP sockets
   -d, --dccp          display only DCCP sockets
   -w, --raw           display only RAW sockets
   -x, --unix          display only Unix domain sockets
       --vsock         display only vsock sockets
   -f, --family=FAMILY display sockets of type FAMILY
       FAMILY := {inet|inet6|link|unix|netlink|vsock|help}

   -K, --kill          forcibly close sockets, display what was closed
   -H, --no-header     Suppress header line

   -A, --query=QUERY, --socket=QUERY
       QUERY := {all|inet|tcp|udp|raw|unix|unix_dgram|unix_stream|unix_seqpacket|packet|netlink|vsock_stream|vsock_dgram}[,QUERY]

   -D, --diag=FILE     Dump raw information about TCP sockets to FILE
   -F, --filter=FILE   read filter information from FILE
       FILTER := [ state STATE-FILTER ] [ EXPRESSION ]
       STATE-FILTER := {all|connected|synchronized|bucket|big|TCP-STATES}
         TCP-STATES := {established|syn-sent|syn-recv|fin-wait-{1,2}|time-wait|closed|close-wait|last-ack|listening|closing}
          connected := {established|syn-sent|syn-recv|fin-wait-{1,2}|time-wait|close-wait|last-ack|closing}
       synchronized := {established|syn-recv|fin-wait-{1,2}|time-wait|close-wait|last-ack|closing}
             bucket := {syn-recv|time-wait}
                big := {established|syn-sent|fin-wait-{1,2}|closed|close-wait|last-ack|listening|closing}
```

Comment: +1 for finally teaching me what "ss" meant! I can't be the only one that wasn't entirely sure why a network utility would be named "ss"...

Answer (score 4):

Try :

```
apt-get install net-tools
```

It also includes, ipconfig, route and arp....